# Does anyone know how I would go about making a map like the Dogs of NYC map?

Tags: javascript, gis, visualization, geography

I am pretty new to the world of web development. I stumbled upon this site quite sometime ago: http://project.wnyc.org/dogs-of-nyc/. I've tried using view source and looking at WNYC's github page and I've come up with nothing. I was hoping maybe some one can shed some light on how this map was created.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The map was built with [Mapbox](http://www.mapbox.com), a service and set of tools for designing data driven maps. Their site has excellent tutorials and they offer a generous free plan. You can do a fair amount without programming but the power features require design and javascript experience.

FWIW, this question isn't a great fit for Stack Overflow. If you get into making maps with Mapbox, Open Street Map or otherwise, and need more specific technical assistance, SO is likely to be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I just didn't know where to go.I am new to make maps and asking for help over the internet.